# Formal alternative to 'can be seen in combination with'

Tags: formality

For a university course I had to write a scientific text about a certain topic and in the text I used a sentence of the form 'The relevance of X can be seen in combination with Y'. The teacher gave feedback on the text and stated that 'can be seen in combination with' was very wordy phrasing and that it would be better to use a formal alternative. I have looked on the internet but have only found synonyms to the word combination. Does anybody have an idea how to rewrite this in a more formal way?

Comment: Context would be helpful. Not sure if X's relevance can be seen in combination with Y's relevance, or whether the relevance of X depends on the combination of X with Y.

Comment: It indeed depends on context, but are you looking for something like "the relevance of X is emphasized by Y"?

Comment: Yes, the context can be seen as follows: There is technology X and on it's own X doesn't seem that useful, but when combined with another technology Y you can see that technology Y can benefit from technology X and that it becomes clear that developing technology X is relevant and has a purpose.

Comment: The phrasing looks just like the majority of other scientific and academic papers I've seen, which often *is* wordier than regular texts. In fact, that wording looks completely normal to me for the subject matter. (And it certainly is formal.)

Comment: This is hardly less wordy or more formal, but . . . *The relevance of X is seen in relation to Y.*